# Fatal exception occur and unfortunately stop

Tags: android

This is Home class.It also give fatal exception and thread exiting with uncaught exception and null pointer exception.After splash screen my application is unfortunately stopped.

```
    package com.example.resproject;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import com.example.getSet.Resgetset;
    import com.example.getSet.Restgetset1;
    import com.example.util.AlertDialogManager;
    import com.example.util.ConnectionDetector;
    import com.example.util.GPSTracker;
  import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Home extends Activity {
        ListView list_detail;
        Context context = this;
        int MAINPOSITION = 0;
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

        EditText edit_search, edt_nameuser, edt_usermail, edt_comment,
                edt_enameuser, edt_emailuser;
        public static ArrayList<Resgetset> rest;
        ArrayList<Restgetset1> rest1;
        ArrayList<Resgetset> restmap;
        static double d;
        static double miles;
        GPSTracker gps;
        static double latitude;
        static double longitude;
        String rating, search;
        Float rate = 0.0f;

        LinearLayout lldisplay;
        Button btn_fvrts;
        int pos;
        RelativeLayout rl_user_dialog, rl_add_dialog;
        public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "Restaurant";
        // ListView represents Navigation Drawer
        ListView mDrawerList;
        String username, usermail, createusername, createusermail;
        String updatename, updateemail;
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
        Button btn_more, btn_map, btn_more1;
        EditText edt_name, edt_mail, createnameuser, createemailuser;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        String foodtype;
        String user2, uservalue;
        View layout12;
        RelativeLayout rl_home, rl_update, rl_create;
        String input, map;
        String emailpattern;
        LinearLayout ll_data;
        String value;
        Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
        ConnectionDetector cd;
        private String Error = null;
        InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
        boolean interstitialCanceled;
        AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
        int MainPosition = 0;
        RelativeLayout rl_dialoguser;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);


            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
            if(getActionBar()!=null){
                getActionBar().hide();
            }
            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            drawer();
            initialize();
            buttonclick();

            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            // check for Internet status
            if (isInternetPresent) {

                if (getString(R.string.Home_banner).equals("yes")) {
                    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
                } else {

                    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                gps = new GPSTracker(Home.this);
                // check if GPS enabled
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line

                } else {
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
                emailpattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
                // initialize

                Intent iv = getIntent();
                foodtype = iv.getStringExtra("foodname");
                map = iv.getStringExtra("map");
                Log.d("map", "" + map);

                // check data is category page or not
                if (foodtype != null) {
                    new getrestaudetail1().execute();
                } else {
                    new getrestaudetail().execute();
            }
                try {
                    rating = String.valueOf(rate);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
                rating = "3";
                edit_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_search);
                // search on home page method
                edit_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int before, int count) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int count, int after) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
                        search = s.toString();
                        if (search.equals("")) {
                            new getrestaudetail().execute();
                            Log.d("search", "" + search);
                        } else {
                            new getrestaudetail1().execute();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {

                RelativeLayout rl_back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                if (rl_back == null) {
                    Log.d("second", "second");
                    rl_dialoguser = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_infodialog);

                    layout12 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                            R.layout.connectiondialog, rl_dialoguser, false);

                    rl_dialoguser.addView(layout12);
                    rl_dialoguser.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                            Home.this, R.anim.popup));
                    Button btn_yes = (Button) layout12.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
                    btn_yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            rl_dialoguser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        private void drawer() {

            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close) {

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    // getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();

                }
                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    // getActionBar().setTitle("Select a river");
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            // all linear layout from slider menu
            LinearLayout ll_home = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_home);
            ll_home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    // new changes
                    Intent iv = new Intent(Home.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(iv);
                }
            });

            // category button click
            LinearLayout ll_cat = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_cat);
            ll_cat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    btn_more1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    Intent iv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Category.class);
                    startActivity(iv);
                }
            });

            // favourite button click
            LinearLayout ll_fvrt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_fav);
            ll_fvrt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    btn_more1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    Intent iv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Favourite.class);
                    startActivity(iv);
                }
            });
            LinearLayout ll_special = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_special);
            ll_special.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    btn_more1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    Intent iv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Offer.class);
                    startActivity(iv);
                }
            });
            LinearLayout ll_about = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_about);
            ll_about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    btn_more1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    Intent iv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
                    startActivity(iv);
                }
            });


            LinearLayout ll_social = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_social);
            ll_social.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    btn_more1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("text/plain");

                    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Restaurant");

                    share.putExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                            "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                                    + Home.this.getPackageName()
                                    + "\n"
                                    + "The great advantage of a restaurant is that it's a refuge from home life. ");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Link!"));
                }
            });
            LinearLayout ll_terms = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_term);
            ll_terms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    btn_more1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    Intent iv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            TermCondition.class);
                    startActivity(iv);
                }
            });
            LinearLayout ll_profile = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_profile);
            ll_profile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    btn_more1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    list_detail.setEnabled(false);
                    // create view
                    layout12 = v;
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,
                            MODE_PRIVATE);

                    // check user is created or not
                    if (prefs.getString("score", null) != null) {

                        uservalue = prefs.getString("score", null);
                        Log.d("user3", uservalue);

                        if (prefs.getString("username", null) != null
                                && prefs.getString("usermailid", null) != null) {

                            Log.d("first", "first");
                            RelativeLayout rl_back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_back);

                            if (rl_back == null) {
                                Log.d("second", "second");
                                RelativeLayout rl_dialoguser = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_infodialog);

                                layout12 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                        R.layout.update_dialog, rl_dialoguser,
                                        false);

                                rl_dialoguser.addView(layout12);

                                ImageView img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                                rl_dialoguser.setAlpha(1);

                                img_back.setAlpha(0.8f);

                                edt_enameuser = (EditText) layout12
                                        .findViewById(R.id.edt_enameuser);
                                edt_emailuser = (EditText) layout12
                                        .findViewById(R.id.edt_emailuser);
                                username = prefs.getString("username", null);
                                Log.d("user3", username);
                                edt_enameuser.setText(username);
                                usermail = prefs.getString("usermailid", null);
                                edt_emailuser.setText(usermail);

                                // updateuser button click
                                Button btn_updateuser = (Button) layout12
                                        .findViewById(R.id.btn_updateuser);
                                btn_updateuser
                                        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                // rl_adddialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                layout12 = v;
                                                list_detail.setEnabled(true);
                                                updatename = edt_enameuser
                                                        .getText().toString()
                                                        .replace(" ", "%20");
                                                updateemail = edt_emailuser
                                                        .getText().toString();

                                                if (updateemail
                                                        .matches(emailpattern)
                                                        && updateemail.length() > 0) {
                                                    if (username.equals("")) {
                                                        edt_nameuser
                                                                .setError("Enter User Name");
                                                    } else {
                                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
                                                                MY_PREFS_NAME,
                                                                MODE_PRIVATE)
                                                                .edit();
                                                        editor.putString(
                                                                "username",
                                                                "" + updatename);
                                                        editor.putString(
                                                                "usermailid",
                                                                "" + updateemail);
                                                        editor.commit();
                                                        new getupdatedetail()
                                                                .execute();

                                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                                                Home.this);
                                                        builder.setMessage(
                                                                "Successfully updated your profile")
                                                                .setTitle("Updated");

                                                        builder.setNeutralButton(
                                                                android.R.string.ok,
                                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onClick(
                                                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                            int id) {
                                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                        AlertDialog alert = builder
                                                                .create();
                                                        alert.show();
                                                        // rl_user_dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                        mDrawerLayout
                                                                .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                                        View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                                        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                                                .getParent();
                                                        parent.removeView(myView);
                                                        ImageView img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    edt_emailuser
                                                            .setError("Enter Valid Email");
                                                }

                                                // img_back.setAlpha(0.0f);
                                                // new getreviewdetail().execute();
                                            }
                                        });

                                // cancel button click
                                Button btn_cancel = (Button) layout12
                                        .findViewById(R.id.btn_canceluser);
                                btn_cancel
                                        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                list_detail.setEnabled(true);
                                                mDrawerLayout
                                                        .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                                ImageView img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                                                img_back.setAlpha(0.0f);
                                                View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                                        .getParent();
                                                parent.removeView(myView);
                                            }
                                        });

                            }
                        } else {

                        }
                    } else {

                        mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        RelativeLayout rl_back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_back);

                        if (rl_back == null) {
                            RelativeLayout rl_dialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_infodialog);

                            layout12 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                    R.layout.dialog_create, rl_dialog, false);
                            rl_dialog.addView(layout12);
                            ImageView img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                            img_back.setAlpha(0.8f);
                            rl_dialog.setAlpha(1);

                            edt_nameuser = (EditText) layout12
                                    .findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
                            edt_usermail = (EditText) layout12
                                    .findViewById(R.id.edt_email12);

                            Button btn_usersubmit = (Button) layout12
                                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_submituser);
                            btn_usersubmit
                                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            list_detail.setEnabled(true);
                                            String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
                                            createusername = edt_nameuser.getText()
                                                    .toString();

                                            createusermail = edt_usermail.getText()
                                                    .toString();
                                            if (createusermail
                                                    .matches(emailPattern)
                                                    && createusermail.length() > 0) {
                                                if (createusername.equals("")) {
                                                    edt_nameuser
                                                            .setError("Enter User Name");
                                                } else {
                                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
                                                            MY_PREFS_NAME,
                                                            MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                                    editor.putString("username", ""
                                                            + createusername);
                                                    editor.putString("usermailid",
                                                            "" + createusermail);
                                                    editor.commit();
                                                    new getuserdetail().execute();

                                                    // new changes
                                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                                            Home.this);
                                                    builder.setMessage(
                                                            "Successfully created your profile")
                                                            .setTitle("Create");

                                                    builder.setNeutralButton(
                                                            android.R.string.ok,
                                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onClick(
                                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                        int id) {
                                                                    dialog.cancel();
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                    AlertDialog alert = builder
                                                            .create();
                                                    alert.show();
                                                    // complete
                                                    View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);

                                                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                                            .getParent();
                                                    parent.removeView(myView);
                                                    ImageView img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                edt_usermail
                                                        .setError("Enter valid email address");
                                            }

                                            // img_back.setAlpha(0.0f);
                                        }
                                    });

                            // new changes
                            Button btn_cancel = (Button) layout12
                                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_canceluser1);
                            btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    list_detail.setEnabled(true);
                                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                    ImageView img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                                    img_back.setAlpha(0.0f);
                                    View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                            .getParent();
                                    parent.removeView(myView);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }

                }
            });
        }
        private void buttonclick() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            btn_map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent iv = new Intent(Home.this, Gmap.class);
                    iv.putExtra("map", "yes");
                    startActivity(iv);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.rotate_in, R.anim.rotate_out);
                    // finish();
                }
            });
            btn_more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.img_more);

            btn_more1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.img_more1);
            btn_more1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // drawer open
            btn_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    btn_more1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_more.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                }
            });

            // close drawer
            btn_more1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_more1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btn_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
        private void initialize() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rl_home = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_home);
            rest = new ArrayList<Resgetset>();
            rest1 = new ArrayList<Restgetset1>();
            list_detail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_detail);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            // btn_fvrts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fvrts);
            btn_map = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_map);
   } }
```

This code is not working..

```
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311): Process: com.example.resproject, PID: 2311
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.resproject/com.example.resproject.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at com.example.resproject.Home.drawer(Home.java:285)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at com.example.resproject.Home.onCreate(Home.java:146)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-04 03:21:38.758: E/AndroidRuntime(2311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

Comment: Post the Logcat also.

Comment: did you define activity in manifest?\

Comment: Now the crash log doesn't match the code in terms of code line numbers so it's difficult to say where the problem is. You should always find the last "Caused by" section. The first line after that is the line where the crash happens, the next one is where the crashing method was called etc. Now the crash seems to be in the drawer() method (line 285 of Home.java) and the drawer() seems to be called from onCreate() (line 146 of Home.java). But that can't be true. So you should check that the code and crash log match. And when they do you'll probably find the problem yourself from the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

your variable `mDrawerLayout`hasn't been initialize before you call `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle)` in `drawer()` method. This probably cause the NullPointerException.
You should call `initialize()` just before `drawer()` in your `onCreate()` methode.

Comment: Still app is unfortunately stopped

Comment: no.. com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView class not found .I already add this class in manifest file

Comment: Not sure why you're getting this error, look and see if Ads sdk is set up correctly :) https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#prerequisites hope you'll find what's wrong !